# Selecionar linha GridView com checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

```js
    function Selecionar(elemento,cordefundo)
        {
            var Inputs = elemento.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var cor = elemento.style.backgroundColor; //manter a cor default do elemento
            for(var i = 0; i < Inputs.length; ++i)
            {
                if(Inputs[i].type == 'checkbox')
                {
                    Inputs[i].checked = !Inputs[i].checked;
                    elemento.style.backgroundColor = cordefundo;
                    elemento.onclick = function()
                    {
                        Selecionar(this,cor);
                    };         
                }         
            }       
        }
```

```
protected void gvSelecao_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e){
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
            row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Selecionar(this,'#FFFF00');");
        }
```

Peguei esses dois códigos de um site para fazer com que selecione linhas da gridview ao clicar nelas.

Essa parte não entendi

```
 elemento.onclick = function()
                {
                    Selecionar(this,cor);
                };
```

Pq ele chama a função novamente? Na verdade entendi, chama a função novamente pois faz parte da lógica: volta a cor padrão da linha e desmarca o ckbox.

Mas não compreendo, pois para mim quando a função foi chamada ela foi encerrada, mas ao debugar vi que quando clico novamente na linha cai direto nessa parte da função:

```
elemento.onclick = function () {
                        Selecionar(this, cor);
                    };
```

Isso que achei um mistério, pois como eu disse, para mim a função foi chamada e encerrada. Tirei um print do que aparece quando clico novamente na linha:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me explica como funciona isso? Pq a função não é encerrada? Se fossem várias funções, elas permaneceriam abertas?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no seu stack trace, como vc está com o seu debugger ativo, vc parou a execução e depois que o seu código do selecionar foi executado, o break point passou pra alguma coisa do jquery. Não tem nada a ver com o seu onclick.

Comment: Poderia por favor colocar o HTML da sua página? @Willian

Comment: Algum resultado? Conseguiu avançar no problema?

Answer (score 1):

Willian,

ele não está chamando a função novamente. O trecho que você está com dúvida quer dizer:

Caso houver o evento de *click* no elemento, então chamar o método Selecionar(this, cor) novamente. O parâmetro *this* significa o elemento que foi identificado o evento de click na tela. O nome disso é Callback e é muito utilizado em Javascript.

Isso explica o porquê quando você clica no elemento novamente a primeira execução é a parte da parte da função;

Espero ter ajudado.